# make a deactivate account with jquery, ajax and php prob

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am adding a deactivate feature on a website i am working on, so I added a form with a textarea to tell the reason why the user is deactivating his account and a button that become enabled when the textarea is filled out so I sent the call via jquery ajax to a php script which will update the users_table in the database to 1 for deactivated then must log the user out and redirect them to the index page of the website. So everything works fine except the log out it is not happening and no redirect. I need help with that please

here is my php script :

```
    require_once '../includes/session.php';
require_once '../includes/functions.php';
require_once '../includes/validation_functions.php';

// this to prevent from accessing this file by pasting a link to it
if(!is_ajax_request()) {
    exit;
}

$user_id = (int)$_SESSION["user_id"];

if(isset($_POST['deactivate_reason'])) {
    $deactivate_reason = mysql_prep($_POST['deactivate_reason']);

    // INSERT into table
    $query1  = "INSERT INTO deactivate_reason_table ( ";
    $query1 .= "user_id, reason";
    $query1 .= ") VALUES (";
    $query1 .= " $user_id, '$deactivate_reason'";
    $query1 .= ")";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
    $confirm_query1 = confirm_query($result1);

    // if query1 is successful and replies deleted then we make the second query to delete the board comments
    if ($confirm_query1 == 0) {
        echo "error";
        exit();
    } else {
        // UPDATE table
        $query2  = "UPDATE users_table ";
        $query2 .= "SET deactivated = 1";
        $query2 .= "WHERE user_id = $user_id";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
        $confirm_query2 = confirm_query($result2);

        if ($confirm_query2 == 0) {
            echo "error";
            exit();
        } else {
            if (isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
                // setcookie($name, $value, $expiration_time)
                setcookie("username", '', time() - 42000, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
            }
            if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
                setcookie("user_id", '', time() - 42000, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
            }

            session_destroy();
            // redirect_to() is a custom function in the functions.php that redirects
            redirect_to("../index.php");
        }

    }
}
```

and here is my jquery ajax script :

```
    $(document).on("click", "#deactivate_button", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var text = $("#deactivate_reason_textarea").val();

    var url = "widgets/deactivate.php";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            deactivate_reason: text
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            CustomSending("Processing...");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#deactivate_reason_textarea").val("");
            $("#dialogoverlay").fadeOut("Slow");
            $("#sending_box").fadeOut("Slow");

            $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: what is `redirect_to()`?

Comment: The method `redirect_to()` exists? Put an `console.log` in your ajax...

Comment: sorry the redirect_to() is a custom function that i made and it is in the functions.php included script

Comment: @firashelou are you sure that the function works properly?

Comment: ok I console.log(data) and i got an error

Comment: @Danielius yes i just used it elsewhere for logging out it is working perfect but i had a problem in the sql query so i corrected it, it was a space thing but now i get printed to the console the whole page html of the index page and it is not redirecting or logging out

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the user for a another page in PHP you can use something like `header('Location: ...')` ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)), but you are calling the script in `ajax`, then you need to put the redirect in this, not in the called PHP script.

To redirect in `JavaScript` you can use `window.location` ([tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/location)).

`window.location = "my/another/script.php";`

In your case, you need to put it in the `success` of `ajax`.

```
   $.ajax({
        ... # your occulted script
        success: function(data){
            $("#deactivate_reason_textarea").val("");
            $("#dialogoverlay").fadeOut("Slow");
            $("#sending_box").fadeOut("Slow");

            $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
            window.location = "another/script.php";
            // or you can put it in a timeout to show a message for the user or other thing
            // setTimeout(function() {
                // window.location = "another/script.php"; 
            // }, 10000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: ok but how can i log out first and then redirect to index page ? I want to be able to log in after to reactivate the account

Comment: You need to put this `window.location` in the `success` from `AJAX`. This will redirect after the `php` file has accessed. I'll update the answer.

Comment: yea ok I did it and it worked but how to log out after deactivation ?

Comment: You need to unset the cookies. I think that are "username" and "user_id", right? Unset these two. Something like: `unset($_COOKIE['username'])`.

Answer (score 0):

ok guys thanks a lot for your help, I managed to solve this with your help
after i added `widow.location = "insert.php"` like tadeubarbosa suggested then i went to my index.php page and added these lines :

```
    if (logged_in()) {
    $email = $user_data['email'];
    $id = $user_data['user_id'];
    $edited = account_edited($email);
    if ($edited == 0){
        redirect_to("editprofile.php?id=$id");
    }

    $is_deactivated = is_deactivated($_SESSION['user_id']);
    if ($is_deactivated == 1) {
        $query = "UPDATE users_table SET online = 0 WHERE user_id = $id";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if (isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
            // setcookie($name, $value, $expiration_time)
            setcookie("username", '', time() - 42000, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
        }
        if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
            setcookie("user_id", '', time() - 42000, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
        }

        session_destroy();
        redirect_to("index.php");
    }
}
```

then went to the login.php script and added a query to update deactivated = 0 if the user logs in so the account reactivates